How early would the first canonical Gospel need to be to (virtually) eliminate concerns over inaccurate memories?
Some scholars have challenged the accuracy of the Gospels by claiming that eyewitness memories and oral tradition methods could not ensure perfect retention and transmission of the extensive teachings and encounters of Jesus, if several decades indeed transpired between Jesus's death and the publication of the first Gospel , and perhaps half a century or more transpired before the publication of the final Gospel, as is the common Gospel origins theory.
For example, in Robert McIver's “Collective Memory and the Reliability of the Gospel Traditions,” he claims that “much can happen to traditions that are preserved in human memories for this length of time.”1 He then "focuses much of his attention on the frailties of memory, in the areas of transience, suggestibility, and hindsight bias. These can drive variations in details and also drive falsehoods, not only when eyewitness testimony is presented in court, but also when past events are remembered in general."2
Therefore, I need to ask, how early would the first Gospel need to be to avoid this challenge to Gospel accuracy due to memory loss and transmission errors?
1 Robert K. McIver, Memory, Jesus, and the Synoptic Gospels (Atlanta, GA: Society of Biblical Literature, 2011), 1.
2 Daniel B. Moore, A Trustworthy Gospel: Arguments for an Early Date for Matthew’s Gospel (Eugene, OR: Wipf  and Stock, 2024), 93; McIver, Memory, 10–11.

Have these 'scholars' not considered that people (especially spiritual people) keep diaries and take notes and write everything down as it happens ?

If you ever played "Chinese Whispers", the answer should be obvious. It's not just a problem of how early a gospel needs to be. The challenge is inevitable.

@kutschkem Re-writing it nearly two thousand years later solves the "Chinese whisper" problem how?

There's a comparable example: the Old Testament scriptures.  Those were mostly transmitted orally, but we do have some manuscripts from different times — which show that the transmission was extremely accurate over hundreds of years.  The Jewish people were very careful about their scriptures; and since many of the early Christians were Jewish, why shouldn't they have been equally careful?

@gidds. Which OT scriptures are you flagging as being mostly transmitted orally for an extended period?

@MikeBorden ??? What I was saying is that memory isn't even reliable enough to be sure 5 minutes later that you retained everything perfectly. I didn't intend to say that's what's happening in the NT, just that you can always argue that, whether it's true and helpful, or not. It's kind of a catch-all if you want to cause doubt. Or in other words, the answer to the question "how early would the first Gospel need to be to avoid this challenge to Gospel accuracy due to memory loss and transmission errors?" is "haha good luck, it can be challenged unless Jesus literally dictated it".

People who don't want to believe can challenge everything. People even challenge the shape of the earth, in our days.

@kutschkem I'm sorry. I thought your position was that the biblical message had been corrupted and needed restoration to its original intent.  Perhaps that corruption only occurred after it was originally written, in which case you're clarified comment makes sense to me.

@MikeBorden In this case I didn't intend to take a position whether or not the text has been corrupted. As for my personal convictions in this matter, they haven't really changed much since I asked this ten years ago: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35705/what-does-it-mean-that-many-parts-which-are-plain-have-been-taken-away But also don't really matter for what I commented here, imo.

@kutschkem Thanks for the link. I was getting ready to try to formulate almost that exact question.  As I understand the answers given there it really wouldn't have even mattered if the events had been videotaped as they happened.  The same corruption that LDS claims still could have occurred.

It could never be early enough to satisfy those who are out to challenge the accuracy of the Gospel accounts. Even if there was evidence that the earliest record started to be written the day after Jesus' bodily ascension into heaven, (not that that was the case) other challenges would be raised. (I note the word 'virtually' in the question.)
Even those who heard with their own ears these words of Jesus would be accused of inventing them, or of 'Chinese whispers' polluting them:

"But the Comforter, the Holy Ghost, whom the Father will send in my
name, he shall teach you all things, and bring all things to your
remembrance, whatsoever I have said unto you." John 14:26 K.J.V.

As Jesus said elsewhere:

"To what can I compare this generation? They are like children sitting
in the market places and calling out to others, 'We played the flute
for you, and you did not dance. We sang a dirge, and you did not
mourn'." Matthew 11:16-17 NIV 1987 ed.

Or, to put that into modern parlance, "There's just no pleasing some folk."
This means that if I spot more questions pursuing other ideas about how the Gospels likely contain inaccurate memories, or biased ideas/beliefs etc, I will not answer them.
Finally, it might be worth pointing out that the matter of when the Gospels were written is distinct from the matter of later copyists making mistakes in transmission (even if working from the autographs). That is just another area where many challenge the accuracy of not only the Gospel accounts, but the rest of the Bible.

Indeed, if one discounts Providential inspiration, why read it at all; to discount what is already disbelieved? +1
